# Convert TCP/IP received ASCII to HEX and put it inside Bracket

Tags: .net, hex, ascii

My printer send me ASCII from TCP/IP port but I need to convert those ASCII to Hex and put it inside Bracket and display on textbox 2. when i run the following code for 0705 Hex it is showing ??75 on textbox 2. my desired output is [07][05]

```
    If TCPClientStream.DataAvailable = True Then
        Dim rcvbytes(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
        TCPClientStream.Read(rcvbytes, 0, CInt(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize))
        TextBox3.Text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvbytes)

        For Each c As Char In TextBox3.Text
            TextBox3.Text &= Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16)
        Next

    End If
```

Comment: What exact bytes get sent from the printer, and what result do you want?

Comment: printer send  ASCII character, i need to covert that ASCII to Hex and put it inside brackets[ ] @Charlieface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your code.

- You are not checking how many bytes were actually received.
- You are not using the correct method to convert to a hex string.
  Either use `Convert.ToHexString` in .NET 5+....

```vb
Dim rcvbytes(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
If TCPClientStream.DataAvailable = True Then
    Dim Received = TCPClientStream.Read(rcvbytes, 0, CInt(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize))
    TextBox3.Text &= Convert.ToHexString(rcvbytes, 0, Received)
End If
```

- ... or you can use `BitConverter.ToString` and `Replace`

```vb
Dim rcvbytes(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
If TCPClientStream.DataAvailable = True Then
    Dim Received = TCPClientStream.Read(rcvbytes, 0, CInt(TCPClientz.ReceiveBufferSize))
    TextBox3.Text &= BitConverter.ToString(rcvbytes, 0, Received).Replace("-", "")
End If
```